# Prove or disprove $d\mid (a^2-1)\Longrightarrow d\mid (a^4-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to prove or to give a counter-example:

> $$d\mid (a^2-1)\Longrightarrow d\mid (a^4-1)$$

**My attempt:**

Yes, this is correct,

First: $(a^2-1)=(a-1)(a+1)\\
(a^4-1)=(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)$

If $d\mid (a-1)(a+1)$ so $\exists k_1 : d\cdot k_1=(a-1)(a+1)$

Therfore $d$ must divide also $(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: If $a|b$ and $b|c$, then $a|c$. Your attempt is correct, except $a^4-1=(a^2-1)(a^2+1)$.

Comment: $a^{4}-1=(a^{2}-1)(a^{2}+1)$ if $d \rvert a^{2}-1$ what can you say about whether $d \rvert a^{2}+1$?

Comment: @sqtrat Ok this is the same $(a^2-1)=(a-1)(a+1)$

Comment: Yes, but that is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorization $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$ is not helpful in proving or disproving this claim. Essential is the question if $a^2-1$ divides $a^4-1$. So, the factorization of 
\begin{align*}
a^4-1
\end{align*}
is relevant. In case the following Lemma is already known to you, you could state:

> Since the following Lemma holds
>   \begin{align*}
> d|m\Rightarrow d|mn\quad\qquad \text{for all } d,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}
> \end{align*}
>   and 
>   \begin{align*}
> a^4-1=(a^2-1)(a^2+1)
> \end{align*}
>   the claim is valid by taking 
>   \begin{align*}
> &m=a^2-1\\
> &n=a^2+1\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

See that $a^4-1=(a^2+1)(a^2-1)$

Comment: Yes, I saw that alaready it's the same as $(a^4-1)=(a-1)(a+1)(a+1)^2$

Comment: So, $d/a^2-1$ implies $a^2-1=pd$ and $a^4-1=(a^2-1)(a^2+1)=(pa^2+p)d$.. So, $d$ divides $a^4-1$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take:
$$
a^2=1+kd
\implies a^4=(1+kd)^2=1+2kd+k^2d^2
\implies a^4-1=d(2k+k^2d)
$$

The fact that we're dealing with $a^2$ is not relevant. The same proof works in general:
$$
d \mid b-1 \implies d \mid b^n-1
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$. You just need the binomal theorem to get $(1+kd)^n = 1+td$.